Courant-Fischer for nonsymmetric matrices
One way to write the Courant-Fischer theorem is the following: given symmetric $A$,
$$\sigma_k(A)=\sup_{U\in\mathbb C^{n\times k},U^*U=I}\sigma_k(U^*AU)$$
where $\sigma_k$ is the $k$th largest singular value. Is there a version of this statement that holds for any matrix? I.e.
$$\sigma_k(A)\le c_{n,k}\sup_{U\in \mathbb C^{n\times k},U^*U=I}\sigma_k(U^*AU)$$
for some constants $c_{n,k}$?
When $k=1$, one can show $c_{n,1}=2$ both suffices and is necessary (by the polarization identity). But I'm looking for references for higher $k$.
